# How to get SUM from two child tables

Tags: php, mysql, navicat

this is my first posting here and i hope i made nothing wrong.

I do get wrong results with sum because i do not understand how to write my query in the correct way.

I have three tables, the first is the master and 2 identical child tables.
The child tables are used for expense and income.

Table forecast

```
id  forecast_id
1   721     
2   721
3   721
```

Table expense

```
forecast_id     amount      tax_free
721             100         0
721             200         1
721             300         0
```

Table income

```
forecast_id     amount      tax_free
721             50          1
721             100         0

SELECT
    t_forecast.forecastID,
    Sum(t_fc_einkauf.betrag) AS expense,
    Sum(t_fc_zahlung.betrag) AS income
FROM
    t_forecast
JOIN t_fc_einkauf ON t_fc_einkauf.forcastID = t_forecast.forecastID
JOIN t_fc_zahlung ON t_fc_zahlung.forcastID = t_forecast.forecastID
WHERE
    t_forecast.forecastID = 855
ORDER BY
```

My result is wrong

```
forcastID   expense     income
855         1200        450
```

It should be

```
forcastID   expense     income
855          600        150
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using joins which creates cross product rows and therefore you are getting sum higher than expected try this with correlated subquery

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT f.forecast_id,
(SELECT SUM(e.amount) FROM expense e WHERE e.forecast_id = f.forecast_id )
AS expense,
 (SELECT SUM(i.amount) FROM income i WHERE i.forecast_id = f.forecast_id )
AS income
FROM
   forecast f
WHERE
    f.forecast_id = 721
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d8ac/9)